# mongoimport skipping first line

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

I’ve come across some odd behaviour when using mongoimport. It seems to be skipping the first line of the JSON import file. I've not seen any mention of headers for JSON, and inserting a blank first line still leads to the same issue.

I'm running CentOS, and MongoImport and the DB are version 2.0.0

The data I’m trying to import contains Japanese characters. It's a bit long but here are the 3 lines I've tried to import. I hope it’s OK to post here in case there’s an issue in the data itself that’s causing the bug.

```
{ "NICT-ATR" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 3, "fluency" : 4 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 3, "fluency" : 3 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 2 }, "output" : "図１２を参照して、本発明の第三実施例に説明説明次に、。" }, "NTT" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "次に、 図 12 を参照して、 本発明の第 3 の実施例について説明する。" }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ed3428a7f7130fdf093a41d" }, "english" : "Next, explanation will be given on a third embodiment of the present invention, by referring to FIG. 12.", "id" : "20000523-155948-EMBODIMENTS-73", "kuro" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "次に、本発明の第３の実施例について１２図である参照して説明する。" }, "moses" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "次に 、 図 １２ を 参照 し て 、 本 発明 の 第 ３ 実施 例 について 説明 する 。 " }, "ref" : "次に、本発明の第３実施例を図１２用いて説明する。", "tsbmt" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 4 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 3 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 4 }, "output" : "次に、説明は図１２の参照から本発明の３番めの実施例上で与えられるだろう。" } }
{ "NICT-ATR" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 4 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 3 }, "output" : "印字機構は、感光体ドラム１１が設けられている。" }, "NTT" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "プリント機構は、 感光体ドラム 11 を備えている。" }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ed3428b7f7130fdf093a819" }, "english" : "The printing mechanism comprises the photosensitive drum 11.", "id" : "19990621-173924-EMBODIMENTS-11", "kuro" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 4 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 1, "fluency" : 2 }, "output" : "印刷機構は、感光体ドラム１１配置構成されている。" }, "moses" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "プリント 機構 は 、 感光 体 ドラム １１ を 備え て いる 。 " }, "ref" : "プリント機構は、感光体ドラム１１を備えている。", "tsbmt" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 3 }, "output" : "印字機構は感光性のドラム１１を含む。" } }
{ "NICT-ATR" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 4 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 4, "fluency" : 3 }, "output" : "図２５は、インデックスコーナー。" }, "NTT" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 4 }, "output" : "インデックスコーナを図 25 に示す。" }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ed3428b7f7130fdf093a6c9" }, "english" : "FIG. 25 shows the index corner.", "id" : "19990630-184545-EMBODIMENTS-234", "kuro" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 3 }, "output" : "インデックスコーナー図２５示す。" }, "moses" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "インデックス コーナ 部 を 図 ２５ に 示す 。 " }, "ref" : "図２５に、インデックスコーナーを示している。", "tsbmt" : { "A" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "B" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "C" : { "adequacy" : 5, "fluency" : 5 }, "output" : "図２５はインデックス・コーナーを示す。" } }
```

The first line never gets imported. I’ve tried varying the order, inserting a blank line in the header and it’s always the first line.

Even more confusingly, mongoimport claims it’s working correctly, saying it imported 3 objects:

```
$ ./mongoimport --file ~/ribes/ntcir-min.json -c ej --drop
connected to: 127.0.0.1
dropping: test.ej
imported 3 objects
```

Then checking the data in the collection returns only 2 results:

```
$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.0
connecting to: test
> db
test
> db.ej.count()
2
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what this could be?

**Update:** Adding an empty JSON object to the first line `{}` makes `mongoimport` say `imported 4` but give the correct output data.

**Update:** When I tried specifying the db with `mongoimport -d ntcir` instead of leaving it to the default `test`, the data imported correctly. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

tried to reproduce on my box
copy the text into a UTF-8 encoded file
run the import command
and it succeeded...

the difference was that I have to specify -h cause default value (127.0.0.1) is not recognisable on my environment...

```
c:\Servers\Mongo\bin>mongoimport.exe --file d:\imp.json -h localhost -c ej --drop
connected to: localhost
dropping: test.ej
imported 3 objects

c:\Servers\Mongo\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
connecting to: test
> db.version()
2.0.1
> db
test
> db.ej.count()
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also verified it works correctly for me. It must have to do with file encoding and maybe Windows. How did you create the textfile?

If you could, try these instructions for creating a UTF-8 file in windows so we can be sure it isn't an encoding issue:

> You may save a file using Notepad (sometimes called "Editor") as UTF-8 but not with Wordpad.

1. Open Notepad
2. Paste text into new file
3. File - Save as -> there you see 3 fields set the last one called "encoding" to: UTF-8

Please let me know if that does the trick.